# Not getting the correct polar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, polarplot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[domain=0:2*3.14159265] plot (xy polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius={2 -sin(4\x r)});
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

this is the example I am using, where I want to plot $$r =2 - \sin(4\theta)$$ in the [0:2*pi] range. [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r=2-sin%284%2atheta%29,%20theta%20=%200..2%2api&dataset=) for example one can see the correct plot. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly multiply the `4` and the `\x r` using `*`, otherwise you're just concatenating the strings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[domain=0:2*pi, samples=100, smooth] plot (xy polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius={2 -sin(4*\x r)});
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]